# Can I change a control's transport in Customizer depending on the previewed page?

Tags: theme-customizer, excerpt

I have a theme with an option for setting the excerpt length for generated excerpts. Is there a way in the Customizer of conditionally changing the transport mechanism, depending on whether the preview page is showing excerpts?

For example, I have another option that controls whether full content or excerpts are shown on archive pages, but the search page always shows excerpts. So I would prefer to not incur the whole page refresh if no excerpts are being previewed, but if it's the search page or the other option is set to show excerpts, I would need to use refresh when the excerpt length is changed.

Or is this even worth the trouble of extra code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the `transport` of a registered setting dynamically after the page loads. And actually the `active_callback` can be used in conjunction with JS to change the `transport` *instead of* causing the control to be hidden.

Assuming you have registered a control with the ID of `excerpt_length`, and you have registered a setting and control as follows:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'excerpt_length', array(
    'transport'         => 'refresh',
    'sanitize_callback' => function( $value ) {
        return intval( $value );
    },
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'excerpt_length', array(
    'label'           => __( 'Excerpt length', 'example' ),
    'section'         => 'something',
    'type'            => 'number',
    'active_callback' => function() {
        // Admin check is for initial state in customize.php.
        return is_admin() || is_archive() || ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() );
    },
) );
```

Then you can enqueue some JS for the Customizer controls app (at `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`) which overrides the behavior for when the `active` state changes, like so to toggle the setting's `transport` when `active` state changes instead of toggling the visibility of control:

```
wp.customize.control( 'excerpt_length', function( control ) {
    control.onChangeActive = function( active ) {
        control.setting.transport = active ? 'refresh' : 'postMessage';
    };
} );
```

There's other ways to do it, but this is probably the least amount of code.

Comment: This solution implies that 
1. The PHP active callback is run once, (on preview page load ?)
2. The JS onChangeActive function is run when the `active` value changes, and this code replaces the function that is normally run.

I tested this (although using `return is_archive() || is_search() || is_home()`), and it does not override the default behavior. My control is not shown on any page, even if I start the Customizer from the front end on a post page.

Comment: @user43242 I forgot to include `is_admin()` in the condition. I just updated the answer. The `active_callback` gets called each time the preview refreshes or you navigate to another page in the preview.

Comment: It's true that this answer depends on the initial state being one where the state is `active`. So that is why the `is_admin` check has to be there, so that when it runs on `customize.php` is is initially `true`.

Comment: That one change made it work on both back end and front end!

I don't understand why `is_admin()` is true on the front end, though.

Comment: The `is_admin()` check is only there to set the state while waiting for the preview to load for the first time. It is true because `customize.php` also runs all of the `active_callback` functions when it initializes.

Comment: But if `is_admin()` will always be true, then how can the active callback ever return false? How could it ever change?

Comment: Edit: Oh, I see that `is_admin` would only be true during the run called by `customize.php`.  That still leaves me wondering why the control isn't hidden, since that's what was happening before I added `is_admin()` (the default behavior was still there).

Comment: Without `is_admin()` then it was checking `is_archive()` which is false since it is in the admin.

Comment: It would be a bit more elegant to actually register a JS subclass of Control which would define the `onActiveChange` from the start. Then there wouldn't be a case where it could get initially hidden. But this would be more code and it may not be as feasible if you are using a custom control already.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution for this. But I would suggest you to use `active_callback` parameter such that if another option that controls full content or excerpts shows full content and the page previewed is other than search page, hide the control that controls the excerpt length.

I guess this would be the better approach as you do want to show the relevent controls as per the previewed page.

Comment: I specifically do NOT want to use `active_callback` to hide the control, because it is always valid to set it. It always applies to the search page, and you shouldn't have to be on the search page to set it. I just didn't want to do a full refresh if it isn't needed.