# How do I get current page ID in Wordpress customizer file?

Tags: php, theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm trying to hide or show customizer settings based on what page I am viewing similar to `active_callback' => 'is_front_page'`, however, I haven't found a way how to access the current page ID from my `customizer.php` file. I want to be able to use `active_callback' => 'is_specific_page'` through a custom callback based on current page ID like so:

```
    function is_specific_page() {

        // LOGIC RETURNS TRUE OR FALSE DEPENDING ON CURRENT PAGE

    }
```

I've tried using all of the following to no avail:

`global $post; $post->ID();` 
`global $wp_query; $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;`
`get_the_ID();`

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Comment: please check url and try: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/get-post-id.html

Comment: @vikrantzilpe sorry, but how is your comment related to this question? This article has nothing to do with Customizer...

Comment: To me this seem to be a duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298752/get-current-post-id-of-customizer-preview-window

Comment: @JHoffmann do you know a way I could implement this solution in vanilla JS?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.

`active_callback` is exactly what you're looking for. You can use it with controls:

```
$wp_customizer->add_control(
    'setting_name',
    array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'section' => 'section_name',
        'label' => 'Option with context',
        'active_callback' => 'is_front_page'
    )
);
```

and with sections:

```
$wp_customize->add_section(
    'section-name',
    array(                                             
        'title' => 'Section with context',
        'active_callback' => 'is_front_page'
     )
);
```

In examples above, this new setting/section will be visible only for front page, thanks to native `is_front_page` function. You can also use other [Conditional Tags.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

But of course you can make your own contexts:

```
function mytheme_is_contact_page() {
    return is_page_template( 'template-contact.php' );
}

function mytheme_is_page_id_123() {
    return is_page( 123 );
}
```

Comment: `is_page()` seems to always return false in every case. Not sure what I’m doing wrong.